# Question about how foreign key data is stored in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I know this is ultra-basic, but it's an assumption I've always held and would like to validate that it's true (in general, with the details specific to various implementations)

Let's say  I have a table that has a text column "Fruit".  In that column only one of four values ever appears:  Pear, Apple, Banana, and Strawberry.  I have a million rows.

Instead of repeating that data (on average) a quarter million times each, if I extract it into a another table that has a Fruit column and just those four rows, and then make the original column a foreign key, does it save space?

I assume that the four fruit names are stored only once, and that the million rows now have pointers or indexes or some kind of reference into the second table.

If my row values are longer than short fruit names I assume the savings/optimization is even larger.

Comment: I understand that you don't *really* want to use foreign keys. Aaah, Marc B has just posted the implications on FKs.
But using a second table as an external "name provider" would definitly save space. You will need an additional index on fruit.fruit_id. This one will be rather small and it will be NUMERIC. Faster than indices on char or varchar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The data types of the fields on both sides of a foreign key relationship have to be identical.

If the parent table's key field is (say) `varchar(20)`, then the foreign key fields in the dependent table will also have to be `varchar(20)`. Which means, yes, you'd have to have X million rows of 'Apple' and 'Pear' and 'Banana' repeating in each table which has a foreign key pointing back at the fruit table.

Generally it's more efficient to use numeric fields as keys (int, bigint), as those can have comparisons done with very few CPU instructions (generally a direct one cpu instruction comparison is possible). Strings, on the other hand, require loops and comparatively expensive setups. So yes, you'd be better off to store the fruit names in a table somewhere, and use their associated numeric ID fields as the foreign key.

Of course, you should benchmark both setups. These are just general rules of thumbs, and your specific requirements/setup may actually work faster with the strings-as-key version.

Comment: Think of a reference type variable 3GL such as C#.NET: its value exits in one location in memory but can have many reference variables that are merely integer (or whatever) pointers to that location. The same principle can be applied to DBMS: logically both tables in a FK store the fruit as text but under the covers the text is stored just once and each table physically stores only an integer (or whatever)  pointer to the same value. Does mySQL do this? I think that is what the questioner is getting at.

Comment: I wouldn't compare mysql's data storage practices against a programming language's. It would make sense to store only one copy, but foreign keys aren't references. they're just a field like any other that happens to contain data that matches the equivalent field/data in another table. After all - dropping a foreign key on a large table is almost instantaneous. If it was a reference, the DBMS would have to copy over the real data now that the reference is gone.

Answer (score 6):

That is correct.

You should have

```
table fruits
id   name
1    Pear
2    Apple
3    Banana
4    Strawberry
```

Where ID is a primary key.
In your second table you will use just the id of this table. That will save you physical space and will make your select statements work faster. 
Besides, this structure would make it very easy for you to add new fruits.

Answer (score 4):

> Instead of repeating that data (on average) a quarter million times
>   each, if I extract it into a another table that has a Fruit column and
>   just those four rows, and then make the original column a foreign key,
>   does it save space?

No if the "Fruit" is the PRIMARY KEY of the "lookup" table, so it must also be the FOREIGN KEY in the "large" table.

However if you make a small surrogate PRIMARY KEY (such as integer "id") in the "lookup" table and than use that as the FOREIGN KEY in the "large" table, you'll save space.

Answer (score 2):

At first yes it will save space because int - 4 bytes, TINYINT - 1 byte. Secondly, searching by this field with TYPE INT will be faster than by VARCHAR. In addition to this, you can use ENUM if your data doesn't change in future. With enum you will get the same maybe faster result than with secondary table and you will avoid additional join.

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is not just about space, it's often about redundancy and modelling the data behavior and also about updating just one row for a change - and reducing the scope of locks by updating only the minimal amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you assume wrong: the values are physically stored repeatedly for each referencing table. Some SQL products do store the value just once but most don't, notably the more popular ones which are based on contiguous storage on disk.

This is the reason end users feel the need to implement their own points in the guise of use integer 'surrogate keys'. A system surrogate would be preferable e.g. wouldn't be visible to users, in the same way an index's 'values' are maintained by the system and cannot be manipulated directly by users. The problem with rolling your own is they become part of the logical model.